# How to Upgrde xps 13 9350 to ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, dell, laptop

I've Ubuntu based Dell XPS 13, 9350 with 14.04 LTS. Want to upgrade to 16.04 LTS. Do we have any official releases/steps for this instead of downloading and installing from canonical?

Request for help?

Jagan.